# Refresh token with Google API

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, google-api, httr, google-fit

I am working in an app which continuously extracts some information related to steps done from some users from GoogleFit API.

I am using the `httr` package for authentication:

```
library(httr)
library(RGoogleFit)

google_client <- gargle::gargle_oauth_client_from_json("client_secret_xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com.json")

myapp <- httr::oauth_app(appname = "myapp", key = google_client$id, secret = google_client$secret)

# Opens a web browser for Google Authentication
google_token <- oauth2.0_token(oauth_endpoints("google"), myapp,
                               scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read",
                               cache = "httr-oauth")
```

I got the access token and the refresh token:

```
> google_token$credentials
$access_token
[1] "ya29.a0AWxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

$expires_in
[1] 3599

$refresh_token
[1] "1//03RHPxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

$scope
[1] "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read"

$token_type
[1] "Bearer"
```

I need continuously to extract the data from the API. So, after the access token expires (one hour) I need to use the refresh token.

Just for testing purposes, I used a `while(true)` loop to see whether after one hour the process stop extracting the data or not.

```
currentToken<-google_token$credentials$access_token
labelToken="current Token"

while(TRUE){
  
  n<-GetFitDataset(currentToken,"derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps",as.POSIXct(as.Date("2023-05-01")),as.POSIXct(as.Date("2023-06-04")))
  
  # When the token expires, the data is not extracted and n$point is null
  if (is.null(n$point)) {
    currentToken<-google_token$credentials$refresh_token
    labelToken="refresh Token"
  }
  
  print(paste0(Sys.time()," ",labelToken," nrow ",nrow(n$point)))
  Sys.sleep(60)
}
```

.. and after one hour **it seems that the refresh token is not recognized as valid**.

After some investigation, I found this [post](https://blog.r-hub.io/2021/01/25/oauth-2.0/#secret-access-token-secret-refresh-token):

[image]

.. however I didnt found enough examples on how to use `httr::VERB`.

How can I use it to solve my problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The refresh token is used to request a new access token. You cannot use a refresh token in place of an access token

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using [refresh_oauth2.0](https://rdrr.io/cran/httr/src/R/oauth-refresh.R) instead of `httr::VERB`.

Here is my code, but the bad new is that `refresh_oauth2.0` is generating a new `refresh token` each time the `access token` expires (one hour). But (If I want) I can use only the first generated `refresh token` to continuously generate new `access token`'s for 7 days. <s>So, many `refresh tokens` will be generated with no any purpose. I'm not sure if is is a bad practice.</s>

EDIT: 06/06/2023
As [John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley) suggests. The new refresh token should be used instead of the olders

```
library(httr)
library(RGoogleFit)
    
oauth2.0_error_codes <- c(
  400,
  401
)

oauth2.0_errors <- c(
  "invalid_request",
  "invalid_client",
  "invalid_grant",
  "unauthorized_client",
  "unsupported_grant_type",
  "invalid_scope"
)

# This implements error checking according to the OAuth2.0
# specification: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-5.2
find_oauth2.0_error <- function(response) {
  if (!status_code(response) %in% oauth2.0_error_codes) {
    return(NULL)
  }
  
  content <- content(response)
  if (!content$error %in% oauth2.0_errors) {
    return(NULL)
  }
  
  list(
    error = content$error,
    error_description = content$error_description,
    error_uri = content$error_uri
  )
}


refresh_oauth2.0 <- function(endpoint, app, credentials, user_params = NULL,
                             use_basic_auth = FALSE) {
  if (is.null(credentials$refresh_token)) {
    stop("Refresh token not available", call. = FALSE)
  }
  
  refresh_url <- endpoint$access
  req_params <- list(
    refresh_token = credentials$refresh_token,
    client_id = app$key,
    grant_type = "refresh_token"
  )
  
  if (!is.null(user_params)) {
    req_params <- utils::modifyList(user_params, req_params)
  }
  
  if (isTRUE(use_basic_auth)) {
    response <- POST(refresh_url,
                     body = req_params, encode = "form",
                     authenticate(app$key, app$secret, type = "basic")
    )
  } else {
    req_params$client_secret <- app$secret
    response <- POST(refresh_url, body = req_params, encode = "form")
  }
  
  err <- find_oauth2.0_error(response)
  if (!is.null(err)) {
    lines <- c(
      paste0("Unable to refresh token: ", err$error),
      err$error_description,
      err$error_uri
    )
    warning(paste(lines, collapse = "\n"), call. = FALSE)
    return(NULL)
  }
  
  stop_for_status(response)
  refresh_data <- content(response)
  utils::modifyList(credentials, refresh_data)
}

google_client <- gargle::gargle_oauth_client_from_json("client_secret_xxxx.com.json")

myapp <- httr::oauth_app(appname = "myapp", key = google_client$id, secret = google_client$secret)
#endpoint <- httr::oauth_endpoints("google")


google_token <- oauth2.0_token(oauth_endpoints("google"), myapp,
                               scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read",
                               cache = "httr-oauth")

currentToken<-google_token$credentials$access_token
labelToken="current Token"

while(TRUE){
  
  n<-GetFitDataset(currentToken,"derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps",as.POSIXct(as.Date("2023-05-01")),as.POSIXct(as.Date("2023-06-04")))
  
  # When the token expires, the data is not extracted and n$point is null
  if (is.null(n$point)) {
    print("NEED REFRESH")
    nt<-refresh_oauth2.0(oauth_endpoints("google"),myapp,google_token$credentials)
    
    currentToken<-nt$access_token
    labelToken="refreshed Token"       
    
    n<-GetFitDataset(currentToken,"derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps",as.POSIXct(as.Date("2023-05-01")),as.POSIXct(as.Date("2023-06-04")))
  }
  
  print(paste0(Sys.time()," ",labelToken," nrow ",nrow(n$point)))
  Sys.sleep(60)
}
```

Comment: Use the new refresh token. Do not continue to use the old refresh token even if it works. Your comment `So, many refresh tokens will be generated with no any purpose.` is wrong and not useful for future readers.